# Parsing an existing text file with no user selection

Tags: javascript, html

Long story short, I am looking to parse a text file (eventually kept on a server, but for now tested locally) that will update content, but will never change file location, name or extension.

Let's say the file is called feed.txt in C:\files.  So, I always want my parser to traverse through the static C:\files\feed.html.

I know am all familiar with

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
```

for user selection, but I want my javascipt parser to skip that all together, grab the file, parse it as such:

```
document.getElementById('file').onchange = function(){

  var file = this.files[0];

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(progressEvent){
    // Entire file
    console.log(this.result);

    // By lines
    var lines = this.result.split('\n');
    for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
      console.log(lines[line]);
    }
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
};
```

and have certain strings being displayed back into my html (code not written yet - still on the parsing part).  How do I go about skipping user file selection and just having the javascript know which file (and where) to parse?

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot read from the OS file system (aside from a user dragging and dropping a file or using a file input) with JavaScript.

Comment: If you could retrieve it over the network, you could use CORS to make it accessible via AJAX.

Comment: How do I go about doing that?

Comment: It's weird that a physical user can select the file location, but the programmer cannot specify said location in the code from the get go

Comment: `parse a text file eventually kept on a server` Huh?  Is this program running on a node server or within a browser?  If on a browser, how will you ever be able to access a file on the server (and meet security requirements)  per http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/ ?

Comment: Jason, in 25 words or less, what is the overall goal here? (funny that @NoahFreitas and I have absolute opposite comments.  From reading the FileAPI spec, you can get access to a file on local host, but NOT from server..  There is other ways to do that, but... ) What's the goal?

Comment: @Jason That's not weird, that's sensible. Otherwise, how easy would it be to write a malicious JavaScript application that reads arbitrary files from the user's hard drive without their knowledge or consent? If you intend to use a webserver for the file in the end anyway, why wouldn't you use one during development?

Comment: < 25 word goal set would be:  Website reads a text file, parses text file, displays parsed code in HTML in browser.

Comment: < 25 word goal:  Txt file is on a webserver, file changes from time to time (but never name or path), website takes text file and parses a line of code from the file (let's say the line between the words To and the first instance of an '!'.  The script takes that parsed code and displays it on a page for the user to view.